# Floating Transparent Window in Android

Tags: android, view, transparent, android-toast

I'm porting my iOS app to Android. Its a music player and I have a window that I display over the top of the app's main screen which fades away - similar to a Toast to let the user know information about the track.

Whats special about this window is that it is semi-transparent. It allows the user to tap buttons which are behind it, so its not a dialog box so to speak.

How would I implement a window such as this in Android? Assume I have a MainActivity with a number of buttons and I want spawn off this special kind of window. Is it just a non-focusable View? Or should I be trying to creat a custom Toast?

Comment: But what about the back of it?? would it be clickable as well?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin: Everything underneath the window needs to remain clickable. By "underneath" I mean everything underneath/behind the window in the Z order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no component that can let you touch underneath but you can create a layout inside the `RelativeLayout` that it support multiple layout on z axis, that will let you touch buttons underneath it.

You can try this sample and **test it**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:clipChildren="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/countdown"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/countdown"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="43dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="97dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="99dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button8"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button9"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Button" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#96000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

That **result**:

[image]

In that image the black semi transparent one is a layout that is on top of the buttons you can use that as a semi-transparent dialog instead. And you can also **click** the buttons underneath it as well.

Comment: Thanks Rod. What you have is exactly what I am after. I will try and implement this in a test app when I get home tonight and accept your answer if it does the trick. Question though: Do I have to use RelativeLayout? My main activity is a bunch of LinearLayouts I believe.

Comment: @SparkyNZ yes you really need to use relative layout if you want it to be on top of other view, As I said `RelativeLayout` is the only layout that support multiple layout on the z-axis

Comment: I could create a RelativeLayout containing my LinearLayouts as children though couldn't I?

Comment: I believe [`FrameLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) also supports multiple views on the z-axis, but then, it really depends on what you want to do/have.

Comment: @SparkyNZ umm ya that would do as well.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin: Thanks heaps Road and Andrew. I have just implemented this programmatically rather than with XML. Had to because all of my widgets were already done programmatically in this case. However, applied same principles and worked fine. So from what I can deduce, every time I call addView() it puts a View on top of whatever is on the View stack. I have a transparent rectangle and I click on the buttons underneath. Most excellent! :-)